# How to convert DataFrame with 0 and 1 to factor with 2 levels (as 0 and 1) in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to implement KTSP classifier in R, and for that it says that phenoGroup must be a factor with exactly 2 levels. Now, my labels for training_data are in the form of dataframe having values 0 and 1 (shown in attached image). I want to convert them into factor with 2 levels '0' and '1'. Can someone please tell me how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need `training_data$phenoGroup <- as.factor(training_data$phenoGroup)`?

Comment: See the guidance on making a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862): a picture of data isn't particularly useful, since we can't copy & paste it. That's not super important in this case since the data is really simple, but in general. Is there any reason why something straightforward like `as.factor` doesn't work? What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you, as.factor() helped to resolve my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
df$phenoGroup <- as.factor(df$phenoGroup)
```

or:

```
df[, 'phenoGroup'] <- as.factor(df[, 'phenoGroup'])
```

both would do the job

Comment: Thanks, as.factor() helped me to resolve my issue effectively